# How to replace text in the InlineResponse window?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to execute modifications on email that I forward or reply-to in Outlook 2016.

The following code executes the modification (replace a regex value with empty) in the InlineResponse window:

```vb
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Public WithEvents myOlExplorer As Outlook.Explorer

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlExplorer = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myOlExplorer_InlineResponse(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' first replace using the word editor
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wdSelection As Word.Selection
    Set oDoc = Item.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set wdSelection = oDoc.Application.Selection
    wdSelection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wdSelection.Find.replacement.ClearFormatting
    With wdSelection.Find
        .Text = "SPECIFIC TEXT WITH A VARIABLE LENGTH OF SPACES OF DIFFERENT KINDS AFTER THAT I NEED TO INCLUDE [!a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z0-9])" ' my regex goes in here the a-zA-Z0-9 part is to work around the non-greedy regex.
        .replacement.Text = "\1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    wdSelection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

When I run this code (which works fine overall), some default behaviour from Outlook is broken.

Examples:

- The draft message is not saved. If I hit reply, type something in the inline response window and leave that message, when getting back the work is gone
- Paste from clipboard doesn't work

Perhaps more features are broken.

What is causing this, and what can we do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a specific property for getting the Word Document from an Inline Response: Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor.

Comment: In this case: myOlExplorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor